# Belarussian travelling to Mexico

Tags: visas, mexico, permits, belarusian-citizens

I'm a citizen of Belarus and have an Italian student residence permit. I'm planning a travelling to Mexico, but I'm not sure whether it is still needed a visa for Belarusians or not. I've found some controversial sources in Internet and unfortunately in Belarusian local segment there is no actual information about this question.

As far as I know it was always required a visa for Belarusians to travel to Mexico. But I've just read about recent changes in Timatic:

*1) Visa required, except for Passengers with a Permanent Residence Permit issued by Italy for a maximum stay of 180 days.*

From this link it's not very clear whether my student residence permit is considered **Permanent**. As far as I understood  - yes, but in one source I read that students residence cards are not enough, so I'm looking for a more reliable source of information.

2) *Visa required, except for Passengers with a valid visa issued
by Canada, Japan, USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member
State For details, click here for a maximum stay of 180 days.*

Sounds good, but may be there is anyone who has already travelled to Mexico with the same travel documents can share his experience? Does this rule work?

**UPD**. The first question is answered: student residence permit itself is not valid for visiting Mexico without a visa.

As for the second one according to the Embassy of Mexico in Moscow the second rule perfectly works, but I don't have any written confirmation yet.

Comment: Your student residence almost certainly isn't permanent (permanent means it doesn't expire) -- but you *do* have a valid visa issued by a Schengen Member State, which seems to satisfy the second option.

Comment: @davidvc all residence permits issued in the EU these days expire. The permanent residency does not expire, but the document itself does.

Comment: @phoog I can't tell if your comment means mine is incorrect or not.

Comment: @davidvc it's not necessarily incorrect; it's arguably imprecise. Permanent residence as you say does not expire, but the card does expire; one could read the comment as if *it* refers to the card, in which case the comment is incorrect, or to the residence, in which case the comment is correct.

Comment: @davidvc, yes,  you are rigth. I mixed up these two notions as italian-english translation was a little bit ambiguous.
But now the situation is even more confusing. I don't have and will not have a valid Shengen visa, because I have this student residence permit.
From the formal point of view visa is not equal to permit, hm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you put into Timatic to cause it to display "Visa required, except for Passengers with a valid visa issued by Canada, Japan, USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member State For details, click here for a maximum stay of 180 days." This seemed wrong to me, as I wasn't aware of any such exception, and when I entered the information into Timatic, [it did not appear](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&HEALTH=1&VISA=1&NA=BY&AR=IT&EM=IT&DE=MX&TR=US&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C).

Since you explicitly stated you're looking for a more reliable source of information, here it is: The Mexican government.

Instituto Nacional de Migración states on its web site which countries' nationals [require a visa to visit Mexico](http://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/paises-requieren-visa-para-mexico/) (and what exemptions exist), and which countries' nationals [do not require a visa](http://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/paises-no-requieren-visa-para-mexico/) (but must still have a tourist card).

As you can see, Belarus is on the list of countries whose nationals require a visa to visit Mexico.

Further, you can see the list of exemptions, which makes no mention of Schengen visas at all.

> No requerirá visa mexicana el extranjero que presente alguno de los siguientes documentos:
>
> a) Documento que acredite residencia permanente en Canadá, Estados Unidos de América, Japón, el Reino Unido de la Gran Bretaña e Irlanda del Norte, o cualquiera de los países que integran el Espacio Schengen.
>
> b) Visa válida y vigente de los Estados Unidos de América.
>
> c) Tarjeta de Viajero de Negocios de APEC (ABTC) aprobada por México.

(and two other exceptions for airline and ship crews)

So, if you have a visa for the US, then it's OK. And if you have *permanent* residence in Canada, US, UK, Japan or one of the Schengen states, it's also OK. But there doesn't appear to be any exemption for your case.

Comment: Hm, I put the following National Belarus (BY) , /Embarkation Italy (IT), Destination Mexico (MX) and got the exception mentioned in the starting post.
Unfortunately the date of the last update of the link you've provided is 10/02/2016 and policy changes I'm talking about were made in may 2016.

Comment: @maty Congratulations, I think you have found an error in Timatic. Eventually I think that is going to cost some airline some big fines.

Comment: @maty There may have been a policy change in May 2016, but I can find no evidence of it anywhere. Not on an official Mexican web site, not on the embassy's web site, nowhere.

Comment: Yep, the main problem was to find any reliable confirmation.
I've made a call today to the Embassy of Mexico in Moscow (where in general belarussians obtain mexican visas) and they confirmed that this exception perfectly works.

Comment: @maty That is good to hear. Please tell them to update their web sites :)

Comment: @maty You should post this as an answer.